# Como declarar um método a ser executado de tempos em tempos em uma aplicação ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, thread

Possuo uma aplicação ***ASP.NET WebForms*** e preciso criar um evento para ser executado em tempos determinados.

O evento trata-se de envio de e-mails.

Acho que li em algum lugar a respeito do ***IIS*** descarregar a aplicação da memória quando alcança determinados tempos sem acesso.

Como não conheço o ***life-cycle*** de uma aplicação ***ASP.NET*** no ***IIS*** pergunto a vocês:
**Qual seria uma forma funcional de criar um mecanismo a ser executado em tempos determinados em uma aplicação *ASP.NET WebForms*?**

Comment: Não existe a possibilidade de usar uma task do windows para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso diretamente em C# acessando APIs do Windows:

Fonte: http://lucasphillip.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/agendar-tarefas-c/

```
/****************************************************************************
 *
 *                         Agendador de Tarefas
 *
 *  Desenvolvido por Lucas Phillip
 *
/***************************************************************************/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyTimers
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Cria uma nova agenda.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="horario"></param>
 class Scheduler
 {
 private static Dictionary<string, Scheduler> SchedulePool = new Dictionary<string, Scheduler>();

 private System.Threading.Timer scheculetimer;
 private StartTime start;
 private TimerCallback MethodCallBack;
 private TimeSpan frequencia;
 private int maxexec = 0;

 /// <summary>
 /// Define ou Retorna o ID da tarefa
 /// </summary>
 public String ID { get; set; }
 /// <summary>
 /// Define ou Retorna a frequência com que a tarefa se repete após sua primeira execução.
 /// Utilize timespan(0) para não repetir
 /// </summary>
 public TimeSpan Frequencia { get { return frequencia; } set { frequencia = value; } }
 /// <summary>
 /// Retorna o número de vezes que que o método foi executado
 /// </summary>
 public int CountExec { get; set; }
 /// <summary>
 /// Define ou Retorna o número máximo de vezes para executar a tarefa
 /// </summary>
 public int MaxExec { get { return maxexec; } set { maxexec = value; } }
 /// <summary>
 /// Define ou Retorna o objeto Timer da tarefa
 /// </summary>
 public System.Threading.Timer ScheduleTimer { get { return scheculetimer; } set { scheculetimer = value; } }

 public Scheduler(TimerCallback Method)
 {
 MethodCallBack = Method;
 }

 public class StartTime
 {
 public int Hour { get; set; }
 public int Minutes { get; set; }
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Adiciona uma nova tarefa que será executada determidado horário
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="State"></param>
 /// <param name="Execute"></param>
 public void AddSchedule(object State, StartTime horario)
 {
 start = horario;
 if (ID != null)
 {
 TimerCallback method = new TimerCallback(Loop);
 ScheduleTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(method, State, StartDelay(), Frequencia);

 SchedulePool.Add(ID, this);
 }
 else
 {
 throw new Exception("É preciso definir um ID para a tarefa!");
 }
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Adiciona uma tarefa que será executada depois de um delay
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="State"></param>
 /// <param name="Delay"></param>
 public void StartWithDelay(object State, TimeSpan Delay)
 {
 if (ID != null)
 {
 TimerCallback method = new TimerCallback(Loop);
 ScheduleTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(method, State, Delay, Frequencia);

 SchedulePool.Add(ID, this);
 }
 else
 {
 throw new Exception("É preciso definir um ID para a tarefa!");
 }
 }

 private void Loop(object State)
 {
 //Adicinona +1 à contagem de vezes que a tarefa foi executada
 CountExec++;
 if (MaxExec > 0)
 {
 if (CountExec > MaxExec)
 {
 Dispose();
 return;
 }
 }

 //Invoca o metedo
 MethodCallBack.Invoke(State);

 //Confere se a tarefa se repete. Se não repetir libera a memória
 if (Frequencia.Ticks == 0)
 {
 Dispose();
 }
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Retorna um TimeSpan com o dalay inicial, baseado na data agendada
 /// </summary>
 /// <returns></returns>
 private TimeSpan StartDelay()
 {
 //Define os minutos antes de definir a hora, pois aqueles podem influenciar nestes
 int waitminute = GetMinutes();
 int waithour = GetHour();
 return new TimeSpan(waithour, waitminute, 0);
 }

 private int GetMinutes()
 {
 if (start.Minutes > DateTime.Now.Minute)
 {
 return start.Minutes - DateTime.Now.Minute;
 }
 else
 {
 start.Hour--;
 return start.Minutes - DateTime.Now.Minute + 60;
 }
 }

 private int GetHour()
 {
 if (start.Hour > DateTime.Now.Hour)
 {
 return start.Hour - DateTime.Now.Hour;
 }
 else if (start.Hour < DateTime.Now.Hour)
 {
 return start.Hour - DateTime.Now.Hour + 24;
 }
 else
 {
 return 0;
 }
 }

 public void Dispose()
 {
 ScheduleTimer.Dispose();
 if (SchedulePool.ContainsKey(ID))
 SchedulePool.Remove(ID);
 }

 public class Control
 {
 /// <summary>
 /// Retorna a referencia para a tarefa
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
 /// <returns></returns>
 public static Scheduler GetTimer(String ScheduleId)
 {
 if (SchedulePool.ContainsKey(ScheduleId))
 {
 return SchedulePool[ScheduleId];
 }
 else
 {
 throw new Exception("A tarefa especificada para cancelar não existe");
 }
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Cancela a tarefa atual
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
 public static void Cancel(String ScheduleId)
 {
 Scheduler schedule = GetTimer(ScheduleId);
 schedule.Dispose();
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Adiciona um int à quantidade máxima de execuções. Se não houver limite, define um.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
 /// <param name="Times"></param>
 public static void AddExec(String ScheduleId, int Times)
 {
 Scheduler schedule = GetTimer(ScheduleId);
 schedule.MaxExec += Times;
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Executa o método agendado.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
 /// <param name="State"></param>
 public static void Execute(String ScheduleId, object State)
 {
 Scheduler schedule = GetTimer(ScheduleId);
 schedule.MethodCallBack.Invoke(State);
 }
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Disponha, se eu puder contribuir mais avise. Se não, ficarei grato se puder aceitar a resposta ;-)